# Using Twilio's transcription from recordings obtained via dial (forwarded calls)

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

Folks, I'm currently entrusted with the task of implementing, while using Twilio, transcriptions for interactions between clients and end users.
After our number is called, I need to make some checks for smart routing depending on the caller number. After that, I proceed to redirect (forward) the call from end user to the number of our client best fit to deal with the user in question. It goes about that:

```
import VoiceResponse = require("twilio/lib/twiml/VoiceResponse");


    const response: VoiceResponse = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    response.dial({
                   action: statusCallback,
                   method: statusCallbackMethod,
                   callerId,
                   record: 'record-from-answer-dual',
                   recordingStatusCallback: `${config.apiURL}/recordings/${app_id}`
                 })
```

By doing so, I get the recording callback to work (I'm using the Twilio's Nodejs library). The problem is that in that case, the dial method (verb) won't take a transcription property in its argument, like when using the record method, like below:

```
response.record({
                 transcribe: true,
                 transcribeCallback: `${config.apiURL}/transcriptions/${app_id}`,
                 recordingStatusCallback: `${config.apiURL}/recordings/${app_id}`
               })
```

In summary, how can I turn on transcription for the records obtained by the dial method (forwarded call)?